# Unlimited requests are started on requesting data within loop asyc

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular with typescript I have the following component class:

```js
@Injectable()
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mycomponent',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html' 
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    public myList : any[] = [];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("url").subscribe(result => {
      this.myList= result;
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  getSubitem(id){
    return this.http.get("url/"+id).subscribe(result => {
      return result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

And following the html snippet:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of myList">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{(getSubitem(item.id) | async)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Now, starting the app and going to that view, `myList`gets loaded and displayed correctly. But the `getSubitem` is triggered unlimited times so that the browser crashes.

How can I assure that the `getSubitem` is only called once for each MyList-Item and the correct information gets displayed?

Comment: Load the subItems into a different variable beforehand and iterate over those in your HTML. `public result: any;` and in subscribe `result => this.result = result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that its continously updating the view, calling the getsubitem() function over and over again.

Here might be a better approach to loading items async:

Component:

```
@Injectable()
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mycomponent',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html' 
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    public myList : any[] = [];
    public subitems: Object = {};
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("url").subscribe(result => {
      this.myList= result;
      for(let item of this.myList){
        this.getSubitem(item.id);
      }
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  getSubitem(id){
    return this.http.get("url/"+id).subscribe(result => {
      this.subitems[id] = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of myList">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let subitem of subitems[item.id]">
      <td>{{subitem}}</td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Let me know if this works for you.